# Action Bar Sherlock + ListFragments + Fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem with the compatibility of the fragments in version 2.2. I use "Sherlock Action Bar" to create the actionbar, but I can not create two fragments. I get this error all the time:

```
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475): java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.pruebasherlock_v4/com.example.pruebasherlock_v4.MainActivity}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
 inflating class fragment 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):
    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-07 12:51:56.124:
 E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 01-07 12:51:56.124:
 E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-07 12:51:56.124:
 E/AndroidRuntime(475): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 com.example.pruebasherlock_v4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     ... 11 more 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475): Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader
 dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.pruebasherlock_v4-1.apk]
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466) 01-07
 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
 01-07 12:51:56.124: E/AndroidRuntime(475):     ... 20 more
```

My main_activity contains this:

```
package com.example.pruebasherlock_v4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

My main.xml contains this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/listaIzq"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        class="com.example.pruebasherlock_v4.Lista"/>

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/detallesDer"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.example.pruebasherlock_v4.Detalle" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And the class "lista" and "Detalle" conteins this:

Lista:

```
package com.example.pruebasherlock_v4;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

public class Lista extends SherlockListFragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }

    @Override
    //se sobreescribe este método como el que siempre "carga" la información a mostrar en el fragment
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    //al hacer tap en algun elemento de la vista, setea el texto del elemento en el nuevo fragment
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Detalle fragment = (Detalle) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detallesDer);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.setText(item);
        } else {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", item);
            startActivity(intent);*/
        }
    }
}
```

Detalle:

```
package com.example.pruebasherlock_v4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Detalle extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);     
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalle, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textoDetalle);
        view.setText(item);
    }
}
```

I feel put much code, but not because it is wrong.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My main_activity contains this:

Please inherit from a `Sherlock` class, such as `SherlockActivity`, if you intend to use ActionBarSherlock. If you *also* intend to use fragments, please inherit from `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

To quote [the ActionBarSherlock documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html):

> When creating an activity to use the action bar on all versions of Android, you must declare your activity to extend any of the activity classes that start with 'Sherlock' (e.g., SherlockActivity, SherlockFragmentActivity).

Comment: Thank you! Extending from SherlockActivity followed me failing, but extend SherlockFragmentActivity works perfect.

Comment: I'm not sure what device you are testing on, but for devices running < 4.0, I recommend using the Support library XML widget for Fragments instead of the native Fragment a la `android.support.v4.app.fragment` instead of `fragment`

Comment: @jsimon: If you are using ActionBarSherlock, as the OP is, you must inherit from a `Sherlock` version of a fragment class, as the OP is doing.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even in your layout XML?

Comment: @jsimon: Your `<fragment>` element in layout XML must reference a class that inherits from a `Sherlock` version of a fragment class, if that fragment will participate in the action bar. An `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class can be used by ActionBarSherlock -- see `SupportMapFragment` in Maps V2 for an example. But if you want to have the fragment add items to the action bar, start an action mode, or otherwise use the action bar, you need to inherit from `SherlockFragment`, `SherlockListFragment`, etc. if you are using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @CommonsWare Learn something new every day. Thanks for point that out. :D

Answer (score 4):

In order to work with compability fragments and ABS you must extend SherlockFragmentActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
```

Comment: Thank you! Extending from SherlockActivity followed me failing, but extend SherlockFragmentActivity works perfect.